# `x <> Nothing` vs `x IsNot Nothing`

Tags: .net, vb.net, syntax

in VB is there any situation whereby `x = Nothing` is not the same as `x is Nothing`?

Also, `x <> Nothing` vs `x IsNot Nothing`

I'm thinking that they are purely identical.. but just wanted to be sure.

Comment: have you tried writing some code to test your hypothesis?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [VB.Net what is the difference between foo=Nothing and Foo Is Nothing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118283/vb-net-what-is-the-difference-between-foo-nothing-and-foo-is-nothing). See [Konrad's excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118283/vb-net-what-is-the-difference-between-foo-nothing-and-foo-is-nothing/3118393#3118393) there (and the comments).

Comment: @MarkJ its not an exact duplicate. is my second line in the question just for show?

Comment: @Parcerier Perhaps the second line is not for show, but it is much less interesting. `IsNot` is **[defined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3bat82c(v=VS.100).aspx)** as the opposite of `Is`. `<>` is **[defined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cey92b0t.aspx)** as the opposite of `=`. Please don't be offended that I've voted to close this as a duplicate, we have a [policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-to-handle-duplicate-questions) that we try to close duplicate questions. It doesn't mean it's deleted, it's just linked to the existing question.

Comment: @MarkJ that does not hold true for nullables

Comment: @Pacerier Sorry, I don't understand. `<>` is the opposite of `=` for nullables. If `a<>b` is `True` then `a=b` is `False`. If `a<>b` is `False` then `a=b` is `True`. And if `a<>b` is `Nothing` then `a=b` is `Nothing`. My point is that once you understand the behaviour of `Is` and `=`, you can easily understand the behaviour of `<>` and `IsNot`. Nullable types **are** discussed in [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118283/vb-net-what-is-the-difference-between-foo-nothing-and-foo-is-nothing) which I have linked as a duplicate. The discussion **is** relevant to `<>` and `IsNot`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a difference with empty strings, which *do* count as Nothing with simply "=" or "<>" but *don't* count as Nothing for Is / IsNot:

```
Public Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim x As String = ""
        Console.WriteLine(x = Nothing)   ' True
        Console.WriteLine(x Is Nothing)  ' False
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: cool so other than strings all other uses would be identical?

Comment: @Pacerier: I don't know enough about that to say for sure - I've just highlighted the one difference I *do* know about :)