# Checkedlistbox equals nothing issue.

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

If have the following code:

```
For Each item As Object In Me.CheckedListBox2.CheckedItems
        Dim PT As String = Me.CheckedListBox2.GetItemText(item)
If PT = "Port 1" Then
            Port1.Sendkeys("command")
            Port1.Sendkeys("{Enter}")
            OtherSub()
        End If
```

This part is so I can do threw each Item in the Checklistbox and add them to the command list.

Now I need to make an If statement that if nothing is selected it will run a default command.

```
 If CheckedListBox2.SelectedValue = Nothing Then
            Reset()
            MsgBox("Wrong")
        End If
```

This this what I tried my last attempt along with several other attempt that I have tried from varies code samples(What I could find) and forums. None will execute the Reset sub or MsgBox.

Other attempts:

```
If PT = "" Then
If PT = Nothing Then
If PT = " " Then
If CheckedListBox2.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
```

Any help if appreciated.

Comment: However, `CheckedListBox2.SelectedIndex = -1` should also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Is Nothing` instead of `= Nothing`

```
 If CheckedListBox2.SelectedValue Is Nothing Then

 End If
```

i also recommend to set `Option Strict` to `ON`, always. Then `= Nothing` wouldn't even compile for reference types which is a good thing.

[What is the difference between 'foo = Nothing' and 'foo is Nothing' in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118283/what-is-the-difference-between-foo-nothing-and-foo-is-nothing-in-vb-net)